# Импорт csv файла в Excel посредством Power Query по шаблону

Tags: excel, csv, импорт, powerquery

Постоянно приходится импортировать данные в excel из csv файлов однотипного содержания. [Образец](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhiEKtfBh5MPi-RdzxCtVwADayNLOw?e=Hb5cEC).  Импорт произвожу через Данные> импорт данных из текстового и csv файла. Далее открывается окно Power Query, жму преобразовать данные, и далее выделяю 3,4,5,6 столбцы, меняю в них точку на запятую, далее меняю тип данных с Текст на десятичное число и нажимаю закрыть и загрузить. В результате получаю такую таблицу:

[image: таблица с котировками после преобразования]

Как-то возможно автоматизировать все эти действия, что-то вроде того, чтобы создать шаблон, который бы при импорте очередного csv файла в excel автоматически заменял точку на запятую в 3-6 столбцах и преобразовывал текст в десятичное число в этих абзацах?

Использую Excel для Microsoft 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно применить немного VBA и PowerQuery.

1. Создаем книгу Excel с двумя листами - "Параметры" и "Данные"
2. На листе "Параметры" создаем таблицу (Ctrl+T) следующего вида:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. На лист "Данные" с помощью PowerQuery стандартными средствами загружаем, преобразовываем нужным образом и выгружаем данные из произвольного файла (как шаблон).Будет примерно такой вид:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Пишем скрипт в обычном модуле. Он будет перебирать имена файлов из "Входного каталога" и помещать эти имена по очереди в "Имя файла" в таблице "Параметры" (потом эти параметры будут передаваться в скрипт на языке М в PowerQuery), а также запускать обновление данных из очередного файла:

```
Sub TransformMany()
    Dim pTable As ListObject, dTable As ListObject
    Set pTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Параметры").ListObjects("Параметры")
    Set dTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Данные").ListObjects(1)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    fname = Dir(pTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 2) & "\*.csv", vbNormal)
    Do While fname <> ""
        pTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(2, 2) = fname
        dTable.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Данные").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs pTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(3, 2) & Replace(fname, "csv", "xlsx")
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        fname = Dir()
    Loop
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

5. Заходим в PowerQuery и вручную корректируем скрипт в "Расширенном редакторе", заменив параметр Источника с фиксированного пути к файлу на наши данные из таблицы "Параметры". Получим что-то вроде:

```
let
    Источник = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Параметры"]}[Content]{0}[Значение]&Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Параметры"]}[Content]{1}[Значение]),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1251, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Измененный тип" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Источник,{{"Column1", type date}, {"Column2", type time}}),
    #"Замененное значение" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Измененный тип",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"}),
    #"Измененный тип1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Замененное значение",{{"Column3", type number}, {"Column4", type number}, {"Column5", type number}, {"Column6", type number}, {"Column7", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Измененный тип1"
```

где наши параметры - это выражение `Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Параметры"]}[Content]{0}[Значение]&Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Параметры"]}[Content]{1}[Значение]`

6. Далее запускаем VBA скрипт и получаем в выходном каталоге Excel-файлы с преобразованными таблицами.

Более подробные видеоинструкции (использовал при подготовке ответа):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxaGDET2lhs
https://comrade-xl.ru/2020/04/30/power-query-pq-vba-transform-and-save-many-files/